# Clustering with Self Organizing Maps including time, date and month as attributes

Tags: distance-functions, self-organizing-maps, real-time

I am about to start up a project on pattern recognition in a highdimensional dataset holding information on transactional salesdata for a company. In that manner I have decided to use the method of SOM to find clusters in the data.

However, I have wondered how it is possible to include the possibility of finding some kind of seasonal pattern? For instance, weekdays are, as far as I know, often modelled as binary. In this way it wont be possible to determine whether there if some certain customer behaviour in weekends, months, etc.

Do there exist a more sophisticated way of including dates, months and time?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the transactional data is timestamped to a resolution of (say) one second, you will need to bin it into to intervals of hours / days / weeks / months etc in order to form time-series vectors for each product / sales location / salesperson etc.

Seasonal behaviour is most often detected using auto-correlation and the use of a [Correlogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlogram). The use of an SOM will help you find clusters of similar sales patterns. Be careful how you normalise your data, though: whether you are more interested in the shape of the sales over time or the size of the sales over time will determine how you should normalise.

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly what I was searching for
https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/encoding-cyclical-features-24hour-time/

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment.